# R: Split dataframe into different dataframes if certain column value is different than the one before?

Tags: r, apply

I have an Excel file which is automatically saved from a certain system, containing various parameters for certain stocks. The file looks like this (simplified :-)

```
Stock Date PE Volume ...
AAPL 01.01.2013 12 1'000'000
AAPL 02.01.2013 11 1'000'000
MSFT 01.01.2013 11 ...
MSFT 02.01.2013 ...
```

Now I want to split AAPL, MSFT etc. in own dataframes. So is there a function or how should the apply function look like to split this whole file into different dataframes as soon as the stock ticker changes?

Comment: I would like to have a dataframe AAPL, a dataframe MSFT, a dataframe xxx containing all the data for this stock. But it should be variable since the number of stock tickers changes

Comment: Have you looked at `?split`?

Comment: ah sorry. We just want to separate it and work from there. Export it to excel, do several analysis per stock etc. I just Need a dataframe for each stock individually. I'm looking at split and subset but this doesn't work yet (df is my dataframe): apply(unique(df[1]),1,function(x){assign(x,subset(df,ticker==x))})

Answer (score 7):

... if you want to export it, than it might be better doing it directy

```
dfs <- split(df, f=df[, "Stock"])
lapply(dfs, function(x) write.table(x, file=paste0(x[1,1], ".csv")))
```

(sorry I don´t have excel, therefore I used .csv)